# Can I see the like/dislike rating of videos before viewing the video?

Tags: youtube

All too often on YouTube there are videos with catchy names that are really still photos or otherwise worthless content.  Is there any way to see the displeasure registered at videos before experiencing it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the browser you use, there are different extensions you can install to get a behavior like that.

[Reddit user bmacs made a browser extension](http://www.reddit.com/r/videos/comments/muf9l/i_dont_have_any_cats_to_show_you_on_my_reddit/) that shows you a bar next to each video on YouTube that shows the the ratio between red/green (downvote/upvote) for each video.

Installation links:

- [Chrome Extension (in-store)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/ytshowrating)
- [Firefox YTShowRating (Firefox Addons site)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ytshowrating/?src=search)
- [Safari Version (direct from bmacs site)](http://billsnitzer.com/ytshowrating/ytshowrating.xpi)

Answer (score -1):

Brother simply download vidIQ extension, this extension is so so so so so so so good, not just only this extension will show you like dislike ratio for every video, it will tell you exactly how many number of likes and dislikes that particular video has